# UX design - unknown progress

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an AlertWindow that has input fields for registration purposes (looks similar to VPN settings in ICS). The form requires network input to be validated, so it can take a bit of time - and I'd like to add a progress meter (actual progress won't be known).

I'm not sure what is the best way to go about it. I can put one into the ActionBar, but the AlertWindow dims out the whole screen, including the ActionBar when it comes up.  Other ways include making a giant progress spinner on top of the whole activity, but I don't like how that would look.

Perhaps I won't need one, and just disabling & changing the text on the register button to 'checking...' or some sort would do?

Any input is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've went ahead and gave the button a different text while it is doing its work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: indeterminate progressbar]
There is usually an 'indeterminate' state for progressbar controls.
Check this [MSDN guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511486.aspx) for different uses of progress bars.

Comment: Sorry, but this is for Android! I thought the tags on the question would be enough.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that it's for android. but I thought the basic principles are universal.

Comment: It's fairly different here in Android land, esp. in a popup window. I went with making the positive button change it's text to "Checking..." while the window was checking whatever it needed to, and I'm pleased with it so far.